# error LNK2019 - I don't understand MSDN's descriptions

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error saying unresolved external symbol_WinMain@16 referenced in function___tmainCRTStartup 
and another error in another line under it saying:
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

```
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;

      int addition (int a, int b)
      {
      int r;
      r=a+b;
      return r;
      }

      int main ()
      {
      int z;
      z = addition (5,3);
      cout << "The result is " << z;
      }
```

it's only a simple addition function program and I'm a beginner in C++ programming.
please help.

Comment: Your code is good but you are using Visual Studio wrongly. When you create a project you must create a 'Win32 Console Application'.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The program isn't a Win32 program. It's just a simple console C++ app.

Comment: @john: that's the right reason. thanks ;)